# Accessing Excel 2010 sheets in another instance of Excel via VBA

Tags: excel, excel-2010, vba

I have a process that generates multiple spreadsheets. It doesn't save them, which is fine because Normally they would be saved manually.
I want to write a macro that accesses each sheet sequentially, perform some magic and then save and close the sheet.
When using Excel 2016, this is not an issue.
But I have Excel 2010 at work, and it cant see any of the work books.

With Excel 2016 this method works:

```
Workbooks("Book3").sheets("B3T1").activate
ActiveWindow.WindowState = xlMaximized
```

with Excel 2010 this is the message I receive:

```
Workbooks("Book3").sheets("B3T1").activate
runtime error '9'. Subscript out of Range
```

What is the method I should use to open an external workbook

Thanks, in advance

Comment: Is your external workbook always in the same repository? If so you could go with a Workbook.open method?

Comment: The workbook is already open. it hasn't been saved. They are Book1...Book18. Each one has two sheets "Table", "Data"

Comment: Have you tried to separate this line into 2 to see if the "out of range" error was coming from the sheet or the workbook?

Comment: it is the workbooks("name") that is causing the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the workbook being accessed is already saved at a location.

This will open the external Files and access them. The macro will also close and save the file.

```
Dim wb As Workbook
Dim fileloc As String
fileloc = "" & "C:namenamename"  & ".xlsm" & ""
Set wb = Workbooks.Open(fileloc)
wb.Worksheets("Sheet1").activate
wb.Close savechanges:=True
```

Answer (score 0):

The worksheet isn't saved by the process that generates the work sheet. That is a manual operation. There are 100 worksheets and I wanted a way to avoid having to maximize each sheet/process it/save it.

The GetObject method finally worked:

```
For ptr = 1 To 100
    Set xlApp = GetObject("Book" & ptr).Application
    xlApp.Application.Workbooks("Book" & ptr).Sheets(1).Activate
    do some processing
    xlApp.Application.Quit
next
```

A one hour+ process is now reduced to 1 second